# Mongoose - MongoDB - Express: Pushing data in a field that is 3 levels deep in a embedded document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

What I am trying to achieve or wondering if it is possible is to put in data into my comments field in my "TopicSchema":

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var TopicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        username: String,
        topic: String,
        description: String,
        category: String,
        created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        posts: [
            {
                postUsername: String,
                post: String,
                postUpvote: {type: Number, default: 0},
                postDownvote: {type: Number, default: 0},
                created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
                comments:  [
                    {
                        commentUsername: String,
                        comment: String,
                        created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
                    }
                ]          
            }
        ]

    });

    mongoose.model('Topics', TopicSchema);
```

Here is what I have so far when i'm trying to push into comments in my TopicsSchema

```
var Topics = mongoose.model('Topics');

        var topicUpdate = {
            $push: {
                "posts:" {
                    "comments": {
                        commentUsername: req.body.username,
                        comment: req.body.comment
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Topics.update({_id: req.body.topicId}, topicUpdate, function(err, status) {
            console.log(status);
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error adding comment to topic');
                res.json(false);
            } else {
                console.log('Success adding comment to topic');
                res.json(true);
            }
        })
```

It is inserting here:

```
    var topicUpdate = {
        $push: {
            "posts:" {
                "comments": {
                    commentUsername: req.body.username,
                    comment: req.body.comment
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It is adding a new posts array and not inserting into the correct posts array that I have in my TopicSchema, however it is adding a new field of posts and the comments are also in that posts, which is not what I want to achieve. I wanted the comments to be added to the correct posts field respectively and not add a new posts field with comments in it every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved it and it seemed to be very challenging with a 3 levels deep embedded document.

My logic was to first find the topic by topic id, then with the data I had received from that, I would have to first loop through the data I had received and if the post id matched with the post id that I was looking for, then I would push the comments to that subarray. After that I would have to use my new data that I had changed and then update the data with the data I had pushed the comments with. The very last thing I had to do was also find the topic again to send to the client side.

Here is the code that I had to finish this with:

```
      Topics.findOne({_id: req.body.topicId}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) { res.json(false) }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.posts.length; i++) {
                if(data.posts[i]._id == req.body.postid) {
                    data.posts[i].comments.push({comment: req.body.comment, commentUsername: req.body.username });                          }
            }
            Topics.update({_id: req.body.topicId}, data, function(err, status) {
                if (err) { console.log('Error updating whole topic'); res.json(false) }
                else {
                    Topics.findOne({_id: req.body.topicId}, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Error finding comments');
                            res.json(status);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Success getting comments');
                            res.json(data);
                        }
                    }) 
                }
            });
```

Yes, I know. I learned my lesson to not use embedded documents 3 levels deep with this type of application now. But hey, it works! :) and I hope that I have helped someone out there as well!